# 'new' notification in RecyclerView with CardView in Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I am using a `RecyclerView` and `CardViews` with some data populated from a Firebase database. If I add an item to the `RecyclerView`, a "new" notification should show within the `CardView`, and after clicking the `CardView` it should dissappear.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: So what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Remove that item from  adapter on cardview click.